# QtCreator: Cannot run compiler 'g++'. Output:

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I've installed the latest Qt through the online installer and with it installed the latest MinGW 64 bit compiler. I'm running windows 10 with the latest updates. Here is an error message upon opening one of the example projects:

```
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'g++'. Output:
===================
# 1 "C:/Qt/5.14.1/mingw73_64/mkspecs/features/data/macros.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "C:/Qt/5.14.1/mingw73_64/mkspecs/features/data/macros.cpp"
QT_COMPILER_STDCXX = 201402L
# 26 "C:/Qt/5.14.1/mingw73_64/mkspecs/features/data/macros.cpp"
QMAKE_GCC_MAJOR_VERSION = 7
QMAKE_GCC_MINOR_VERSION = 3
QMAKE_GCC_PATCH_VERSION = 0
===================
Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
Error while parsing file C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.14.1\widgets\itemviews\addressbook\addressbook.pro. Giving up.
```

Here is my kit and compiler setup:

[image: kit]

[image: compilers]

I can confirm that `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\bin\g++.exe exists`, and `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\bin` is also added to PATH. I've tried the offline installer as well, with and without admin permissions but it didn't work. Everything seemingly looks fine (no red highlights or anything like that) so what is the problem here? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I have a Ryzen 3 CPU, and from reading the qt forums there was a rare bug where Qt would fail to install without upgrading the BIOS. I updated mine and Qt installation went well. Just something that could be relevant.

Comment: Do you have this file?
`C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.14.1\widgets\itemviews\addressbook\addressbook.pro`

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus Yes, it is included. It's not just example projects, it fails also on new projects.

Comment: did you solve the issue?@SteveHemmingsen